# Finding intergenic regions

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I would like to extract the intergenic coordinates for a chromosome. I made a chunk of code, but as I am new to these packages, I am not sure if I follow the right logic here:

```
library(IRanges)
library(GenomicFeatures)
library(TxDb.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19.knownGene)
txdb = transcriptsBy(TxDb.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19.knownGene, by = "gene",use.names=TRUE)

#For example, only I am interested in intergenic coordinates in chromosome 1
seqlevels(txdb, force=TRUE) = c("chr1")

#Creates IRanges 

ir = IRanges(start=unlist(start(txdb)), end=unlist(end(txdb)), names=names(txdb)) 

# Reduce overlapping gene positions to continuous range
ir.red = reduce(ir) # Collapses ranges of overlapping genes to continuous range.

#Identify overlaps among the initial and reduced range data sets
overlap = findOverlaps(ir, ir.red)
```

Do I have to take care of "+" and "-" strand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest method is to start with the genes() accessor, reduce() that and take the complement:

```
library(TxDb.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19.knownGene)
genic <- genes(TxDb.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19.knownGene)
genic <- reduce(genic, ignore.strand=T)
intergenic <- gaps(genic)
intergenic <- intergenic[strand(intergenic) == "*"] #This is important!!!
```

The last step is really important, as otherwise you'll get an additional 2 entries per chromosome (one for each of + and -).

Answer (score 0):

While not a direct answer to your question, it's worth mentioning that you can get these data directly from the UCSC Table Browser, http://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgTables. The table browser allows you to set intersections between two tracks or their complements, which can even be returned to a custom track within the table browser for further operations, allowing for arbitrarily complex nested queries against multiple tracks and tables. Steps for your purposes are as follows...

1) Select your genome and assembly of interest.

2) Choose "Genes and Gene Predictions" as the group, "UCSC Genes" as the track and "knownGene" as the table.

3) If you want a single chromosome or part of a chromosome, enter it in the box on the "region" line, otherwise leave it set to "genome"

4) Click on "create" on the "intersection" line

5) Once on the next page, select group="Mapping and Sequencing", track="Assembly", table="Assembly (gold)", click the radio button "Base-pair-wise intersection (AND) of UCSC Genes and Assembly", check the box "Complement UCSC Genes before base-pair-wise intersection/union", and click "submit".

6) Back on the main Table Browser screen, enter whatever you want for output options and hit "get output" to retrieve the intergenic regions.

Happy hunting!